# send multiple request for the same rest api javascript

Tags: node.js, express

I have an end point. I need to call this end point 5 times on a single call. Response from every call needs to passed onto another API call.

How do I do it using `request-promise` package.

const rp = require('request-promise')

```
app.get('', (req, res) => {
    let topFiveArr = [];

    const businessOptions = {
        url: businessUrl,
        json: true
    };

    rp(businessOptions)
        .then((businessBody) => {    // I am not sure hot to call it 5 times
            // call another API
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the async/await syntax things get easier. For example:

```js
app.get('', async (req, res) => {
    const businessOptions = {
        url: businessUrl,
        json: true
    };

    let priorResult = await rp(businessOptions);
    for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
        priorResult = await rp(priorResult);
    }
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to do with the results and the exact format of the responses you'll likely need to add some extra processing steps (e.g. to convert the raw response into something you can pass to `rp()`).